# Scikit-learn - Warm-restarts for Cross Validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

The developers guide in the sklearn documentation (link below) has a section header that caught my eye - ["A sample algorithmic trick: warm restarts for cross validation"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/performance.html#a-sample-algorithmic-trick-warm-restarts-for-cross-validation)

Unfortunately, currently the section just says "TODO: demonstrate the warm restart tricks for cross validation of linear regression with Coordinate Descent."

grid_search.GridSearchCV and grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV do not have a warm-start parameter, so I would guess using warm-restart during cross validation would require an estimator that supports warm-start. But there's also an open github issue where a developer says  ["Due to how GridSearchCV is designed (use of clone, parallelism with n_jobs), setting the warm_start option wouldn't have any effect. It would be nice to create a grid search object which can benefit from warm-start."](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1674)

Is there a way to implement the "algorithmic trick: warm restarts for cross validation" in sci-kit learn 0.17?

EDIT: or in 0.18 now that it is released?

Comment: I can't be sure that this is what they meant, but I'd assume that this just refers to using the warm-start parameter for the estimator being cross-validated.  If you specifically want to implement a grid search supporting warm-start, then I don't think cross-validation is the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, and its been a while since this question is posted, but I am not able to understand the benefit of having warm_start into cross-validation. Isnt it wrong to use previous knowledge (tuned params from previous call to `fit()`) in next fold of the data. In my opinion that would lead to data leakage and may give wrong (inflated) results on subsequent folds. Please explain more about your use case

Comment: Hi Vivek, I think you raise a good point. It's a long time since I posted this, I'm not sure what I was looking for then, beyond presumably wondering about something hinted in the docs about how to speed up model-search.

Comment: Oh ok. Actually I saw the issue you linked (and the issues linked therein) but could not find out the main reason, hence asked here. Nevermind, I will add my query to that issue. Thanks